# Citizen's Patrol Badge... why?

Tags: support, badges

I just got awarded the [Citizen's Patrol badge](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/badges/8/citizen-patrol)... but I don't think I flagged anything recently.

Anyone know why that might happen?

Answer (score 3):

Because you flagged something for moderator attention, probably in the past.

[Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange)

> 2011-02-09: Flagging for moderator attention now counts for the Citizen Patrol badge. This change applies retroactively.

Comment: Hahahaha! So now - when I ask a moderator to make my own question CW - I get a badge!?

Comment: @Leguri, it's a one time badge I think.

Comment: How does this badge work? I've flagged one post on RPG and two on Stack Overflow but haven't received the badge on either.